# Executable built with CMake(Visual Studio 2015) needs Qt5SVG.dll but original Visual Studio 2015 does not. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, external-dependencies, cmake-modules

## Situation

I learned a lot over the last year, but this is something I just could not wrap my head around. Project is `C++`. CMake `1.15.2`. Visual Studio `2015`.

I converted a whole Solution `*.sln` file with [cmake-converter](https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter) and wrote FindXXX.cmake Modules for all external `*.lib`s defined in the `*.vcxproj` files.

Everytime I encountered an `error: unresolved external` I added the corresponding Target `Sometarget::somecomponent` to the `target_link_libraries(ConsumingTarget ... )` call.

Now I have a build that works and produces no errors. Some executables say something along the lines of:

"Execution of code cannot be continued because somecomponent.dll is not found..."

#### I have

- An original `.sln` file that produces executables only requiring `.lib` files
- A CMake generated `.sln` file that produces executables requiring `.dll` files
- Working FindXXX.cmake files which `add_library(XXX::yyy UNKNOWN IMPORTED)`

  - They find the headers and the `.lib` files (`.dll` files are not existing/intended/needed in the original VS `.sln`)
  - They create the corresponding Targets for all `.lib` files
- Consuming Targets which `target_link_libraries(ConsumingTarget PRIVATE XXX::yyy)`
- "A working build"
- An error "before starting the main function".

#### What I have tried

I have tried [defining an OBJECT Library](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16931#note_273637) and adding this to the sources of `ConsumingTarget` and removing `Sometarget::somecomponent` from the `target_link_libraries` call. [CMake Doc on Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries)

I have tried reading and understanding the difference between [module and library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099975/difference-between-a-module-library-and-a-framework). Even the CMake documentation on [imported Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html?highlight=add_library#imported-libraries) couldn't help me understand my problem.

I have tried reading and understanding the difference between linking a static and shared library.

#### My Assumptions

- Adding the imported library is done wrong by me.

  - Reason: [DependenciesGui.exe](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) shows different dependencies for the cmake-generated-executable and the original-sln-executable but the linker calls (shown in VisualStudio 2015) seem to be the same.
- Whole Program Optimization in the CMake File does not work the same way it does in the original .sln file although the Flags are activated at all levels described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439179/9740720).

  - Reason: compiling with the original file I noticed `warning C4505: 'foobar': unreferenced local function has been removed` - I don't seem to get those warnings with the cmake-generated build.
  - subassumption: Functions which won't be called are optimized away, thus removing the necessity for the `.dll` file.

## I expect/hope for

- `ConsumingTarget.exe` to run without asking for `somecomponent.dll`
- another explanation on imported targets and how to link libraries where `.dll`s should not be necessary.
- an explanation on how to analyze/compare the two binaries regarding their symbols(?) and map the seen information to CMake commands. (I am using [DependenciesGui.exe](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to look for dependencies in the .exe file)

## Possible reason for failure

- One executable had [no /DELAYLOAD... directive](https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter/issues/89) after conversion with cmake-converter. Opened Issue. Question Title still holds.

Edits: 
1: Added possible reason for failure